# Why addListener() typically returns void?

Tags: java, coding-style, listener, return-value

Am seeing that a typical addXXXListener() returns void !
I have seen this as a practice across the board whether it is UI frameworks (like Swing) or server-side frameworks.

For ex:
Class: [AsyncContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html)

```
public void addAsyncListener(AsyncListener listener);
```

Class: [AbstractButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.htm)

```
public void addActionListener(ActionListener l)
```

And numerous other examples...

Shouldnt we be interested to know if the add listener call completed successfully ?
What if the component was in a state where the listener could not be added ?

For ex: Consider the Guava library [ListenableFuture](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#addListener(java.lang.Runnable, java.util.concurrent.Executor))

It has a

```
void addListener(Runnable listener, Executor exec);
```

Its behavior is that the listener is executed when the Future's computation is complete.
They took the approach that, if the Future is already complete then the listener would be called immediately. Even if the future was completed ages back.
There is no indication to the user that they are calling addListener() unnecessarily on an already completed future !

I would think the addListener() should be capable of returning a value(boolean?) that says if the listener could be successfully added and let the caller do the handling if the listener could not be added !

I know there must be some reason why all addListeners are written this way.
I just dont know why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These methods generally simply add your listener to a list. The circumstances in which it would not work are generally outside your control (think out of memory error for example) and would trigger an exception anyway.

The reason why `Collection#add`, for example, returns a boolean is that some implementations will only add the item if some conditions are met (e.g. Sets won't add an item if it is a duplicate). Note that [this is the only situation when `Collection#add` will return false](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29) (other reasons will trigger an exception):

> If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns.

This was probably deemed not very useful for `addListener`.

Comment: answering is truly an art. thanks for such a well-written (yet short) answer.

Answer (score 1):

In all these cases, there's no possible way the listener could fail to be added.

> Even if the future was completed ages back.

So what if the future was completed ages back?  If you want to add a listener to the `Future`, you want to do something with that result whenever it's completed, whether that was ages ago or in the future.

Comment: Ok. Here is the problem. Suppose I have a CustomFuture and my listener interface has two methods: onStart() and onComplete(). When I do a addListener(listener); on a Future that is already completed, you think onStart() should be called again ? And also the onComplete() ?

Comment: I think you'd need to decide that for your own `CustomFuture` interface.

Comment: ofcourse that is for me to decide. I am just trying to make a case for returning a result from an addListener(). It is indeed dependent on the use-case. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

The convention is to return information to the caller if the caller can be expected to act on the information.

The ListenableFuture is a very different use case to most addXXXListener() calls. These are expected to return immediately and be 100% successful in normal operation (e.g. just adding a listener to some internal list structure) and there is no actionable information to return to the caller. (However, in non-normal operation you would probably expect it to throw an unchecked Exception).

One possible variation is to treat this as a mutator operation and extend the usual Collection pattern to return a boolean if the internal data structure has been modified by the addXXXListener() call. Although this only returns useful information if the caller is not aware whether or not it has already added itself...